# How to build a good registration mechanism in python?

Tags: python, python-import

I want to build a well-modularized python project, where all alternative modules should be registed and acessed via a function named `xxx_builder`.

Taking data class as an example:

**register.py**:

```
def register(key, module, module_dict):
    """Register and maintain the data classes

    """
    if key in module_dict:
        logger.warning(
            'Key {} is already pre-defined, overwritten.'.format(key))
    module_dict[key] = module

data_dict = {}

def register_data(key, module):
    register(key, module, data_dict)
```

**data.py**:

```
from register import register_data
import ABCDEF

class MyData:
    """An alternative data class
    
    """
    pass

def call_my_data(data_type):
    if data_type == 'mydata'
        return MyData

register_data('mydata', call_my_data)
```

**builder.py**:

```
import register

def get_data(type):
    """Obtain the corresponding data class 

    """ 
    for func in register.data_dict.values():
        data = func(type)
        if data is not None:
            return data
```

**main.py**:

```
from data import MyData
from builder import get_data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data_type = 'mydata'
    data = get_data(type=data_type)
```

### My problem

In `main.py`, to register `MyData` class into `register.data_dict` before calling the function `get_data`, I need to import `data.py` in advance to execute `register_data('mydata', call_my_data)`.

It's okay when the project is small, and all the data-related classes are placed according to some rules (e.g. all data-related class should be placed under the directory `data`) so that I can import them in advance.

However, this registeration mechanism means that all data-related classes will be imported, and I need to install all packages even if I won't use it actually. For example, when the indicator `data_type` in `main.py` is not `mydata` I still need to install `ABCDEF` package for the class `MyData`.

So is there any good idea to avoid importing all the packages?

Comment: see singleton design pattern

Comment: @sahasrara62  can you be more specific, thks

Comment: Alternatives to importing all the packages so they can register themselves... you could have `data_dict` as a handwritten config value, or you could have a naming convention for data/call_my_data files so they can be imported only when needed by builder. You could also combine those by having a naming convention for default data handlers, with a config dict that allows to specify extra or overridden data handlers in non-default locations.

Comment: @Anentropic thks, I have thought about the solution of taking `data_dict` as a handwritten config. However, I'm looking for a way that the contributors don't need to modify two files (`data_dict` and new data class).

Comment: it would help to see a more concrete use case

Answer (score 0):

Python's packaging tools come with a solution for this: [entry points](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/entry-points/). There's even a tutorial about [how to use entry points for plugins](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/creating-and-discovering-plugins/#using-package-metadata) (which seems like what you're doing) (in conjunction with [this Setuptools tutorial](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/entry_point.html#entry-points-for-plugins)).

IOW, something like this (nb. untested), if you have a plugin package that has defined

```
[options.entry_points]
myapp.data_class =
    someplugindata = my_plugin.data_classes:SomePluginData
```

in setup.cfg (or pypackage.toml or setup.py, with their respective syntaxes), you could register all of these plugin classes (here shown with an example with a locally registered class too).

```
from importlib.metadata import entry_points

data_class_registry = {}


def register(key):
    def decorator(func):
        data_class_registry[key] = func
        return func

    return decorator


@register("mydata")
class MyData:
    ...


def register_from_entrypoints():
    for entrypoint in entry_points(group="myapp.data_class"):
        register(entrypoint.name)(entrypoint.load())


def get_constructor(type):
    return data_class_registry[type]


def main():
    register_from_entrypoints()
    get_constructor("mydata")(...)
    get_constructor("someplugindata")(...)
```

Comment: Thanks, it's a good try to use entry points, but it maybe inappropriate when I have lots of alternatives (let's say 100), where I need to build an entry point for each of them. Also, in my opinion the alternative modules should be accessible only within the project. For example, if the alternative modules are some data classes, it's inappropriate to call them in the terminal. (I' new to `entry point`, maybe I have some misunderstandings about it.)

Comment: "build an entrypoint" means "write a function and declare it in a configuration file". I'm not quite sure I'm following your "accessible only within the project" thing. If you _don't_ need plugins, then using a metaclass for implicitly registering classes would be even easier.